# running ruby on server having coldfusion already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coldfusion

I am running a coldfusion9 server on IIS and it is working good, Now i have some ruby code which i want to to place on my server and and i should be able to run it,

how can i configure the IIS to install ruby side by side with coldfusion or someother way like installing on the same machine but on different port and call it using `cfhttp` so at least i should be able to make use of both ruby and coldfusion

if i follow a second technique, suppose i install ruby on `localhost:9000` and the 
hostname is: `www.degno.com` for `localhost` and with `cfhttp` will i be able to call

```
http://www.degno.com:9000/
```

Comment: Ruby is a programming language. It doesn't install on any port. You probably mean Rails, and yes you can run Rails on any port you like.

Comment: Rails, Sinatra, Padrino, Rack, all can handle HTTP requests. You need to be more explicit in your question.

Comment: guys, thanks for the answers, but my question is bit more than only involving ruby

Answer (score 1):

Good ol' Coldfusion. I was a Coldfusion dev before moving to Ruby.

EDIT:
There are a lot of hacks to install ruby on IIS. I wouldn't recommend this.

So, this is what I would do.

1. I would install, depending on your application, Sinatra or Rails
2. I would configure [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html)/Rails to run on a specified port, maybe using [unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)
3. I would configure Sinatra/Rails to [run as a service](https://thattommyhall.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/srvany-sinatra-ruby-windows-service/)
4. I would make sure that the Sinatra/Rails app runs in the broswer using the specified port
5. I could then query the ruby code using the cfhttp tag

I hope this answers your question and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks but my question even if i am able to successfully run somehow ruby on rails on localhost:9000, how will i use the localhost:9000 to assign it to a website address so the same website one one port calls coldfusion and on another port it runs ruby code.

Comment: I think you need to modify your hosts file. See this http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hosts-file-in-windows

Comment: If the answer worked for you, could you accept it? Thanks!

Comment: hi i have not tried it completely, i wil accept answer if it works for me